# Can a Class attribute in python be a list

Tags: python

I am trying to lean and practice creating/using classes and objects in python.  One challenge problem I am stuck on is making multiple objects of the same class interact with each other.  We had to create a class with different objects that would be "users" and these user's have to be able to "follow" each other.
Sorry if anything is not clear, I'm new to this site.

My first attempt was this:

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name, race, age, following= None): 
        self.name= name
        self.race= race
        self.age= age 
        self.following= following

    def introduce_self(self):
        print (self.name)
        print (self.following)

    def imFollowing(self):
        print (self.following.name)    

u1= User("Bob", "White", 20)
u4= User("Sally", "Asian", 22, u1)
u3= User("Mike", "Black", 19, u1)
u2= User("Sandra", "Hispanic", 25, u4)
```

But this only works if each user is following exactly one other user.
Does anyone know how I could make it so that each user can follow multiple other users.  I have a vague idea that I have to make the "following" attribute of the class a list but am not sure how to do this.

EDIT: I seemed to have violated some unwritten rule with this post based on comments I'm getting.  Sorry people it's my first time ever on here and I didn't know what the "spirit of SO" is.

Comment: have you tried passing `list` of users to constructor, here your hint: make last param as `[u1, u2]` does that get you started?

Comment: Ok so the first thing is you need class methods which assign to class members, not just print things which then disappear when the method finishes. And yes you want to make `following` a list. So you initialize it to `[]`, and then `.append()` to it.

Comment: Please try to code it yourself, and when you get stuck, edit your question with the your code and describe what it's doing wrong, then we'll help. That's the spirit of SO.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) Like @smci said, the point is that you should try it yourself, then if you hit a problem, ask a question about that.

Comment: Incidentally, these are instance attributes, not class attributes.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: yes thanks. I meant to say 'your class needs methods which assign to instance attributes, like `self.following`'.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comments.  FYI I did try many different attempts to solve the problem, none of them worked and so I came her to post the question.  I thought posting all of my attempts would make the post to long and confusing and no one would answer it.

Comment: In the future, please at least post one such attempt. Perhaps the one you thought was most promising.

Comment: Jomar: welcome to SO. Was just letting you know for next time to please post your code attempt (that's what they mean when they say 'MCVE' here). And please do [read the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help) through.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the `following` attribute as a set (unordered, unique collection).

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, name, race, age, following=None): 
        self.name= name
        self.race= race
        self.age= age 
        self.following= following if following else set() # init with empty set if no following users provided

    def introduce_self(self):
        print (self.name)
        print (self.following)

    def imFollowing(self):
        for f in self.following:
            print(f.name)

    # you can add method for adding users to follow not only during User initiation.
    def add_follow(self, user):
        # add current user as a follower to the provided user
        self.following.add(user)

u1= User("Bob", "White", 20)
u4= User("Sally", "Asian", 22, {u1})
u3= User("Mike", "Black", 19, {u1, u4})
u1.add_follow(u4)
u1.imFollowing() # OUTPUT: sally
```

Comment: Ok but please don't write the OP's assignment for them when they just post a spec... that's contrary to the spirit of SO. Encourage them to post their own code then help them fix it.

Comment: Also, `set` is a better choice then `list`, but new users will only know about list, and the OP specifically said they intended to do list, so I'd keep it simple (code it with a list, and mention set in a footnote).

Comment: @smci I agree with your first comment but beg to differ on the second. For me personally, the best way to learn is when more experienced developers introduce me to new concepts, paradigms, data structures, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  And I agree, I learn so much better when I can work backwards and breakdown a completed solution @Gabip

Comment: @JomarRoyer Happy to help. And if you find it helpful, please accept the answer to help other developers who struggling with same issue :)